# API download with curl command for date ranges

Tags: python, json, api, curl

I am trying to download short equity from FINRA, I was able to download only for a specific date as below.
curl -L -d "{ "compareFilters": [ { "compareType": "EQUAL", "fieldName": " settlementDate", **"fieldValue": " 2018-06-15"** } ] ,"limit":5 } " -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST https://api.finra.org/data/group/otcMarket/name/EquityShortInterest

But I am trying to download the data for the particular dates range such as start: 2018-06-15, end: 2018-06-14. So, I tried this follow codes in the field values.

curl -L
-d "{ "compareFilters": [ { "compareType": "EQUAL", "fieldName": " settlementDate", "fieldValue": ">2018-06-01 00:00:00&&<=2018-07-01" } ] } "
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
-H "Accept: application/json" -X POST https://api.finra.org/data/group/otcMarket/name/EquityShortInterest

Then, I converted it into json format to run in python.
When I run that json format with date ranges as below;

jsonout = response.json()
jsonout

I got this error:

{'statusCode': 400,
'statusDescription': 'Bad Request',
'requestId': 'ab7af2fe-9189-4619-b0ca-ee368fb6e91d',
'message': 'Unable to parse request body.'}

And It would be appreciated if somebody could help me because I am not familiar with curl or json that much and coding is not my professional career as I come from accounting.

This is my converted json format.
import requests

headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json',
}

data = {
'{ "compareFilters": [ { "compareType": "EQUAL", "fieldName": " settlementDate", "fieldValue": ">2018-06-01 00:00:00': '',
'<': '2018-07-01" } ] }'
}

response = requests.post('https://api.finra.org/data/group/otcMarket/name/EquityShortInterest', headers=headers, data=data)

Thank you

Comment: This is my converted json format.                                              
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}

data = {
  '{ "compareFilters": [ { "compareType": "EQUAL", "fieldName": " settlementDate", "fieldValue": ">2018-06-01 00:00:00': '',
  '<': '2018-07-01" } ] }'
}

response = requests.post('https://api.finra.org/data/group/otcMarket/name/EquityShortInterest', headers=headers, data=data)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
curl -L -d '{ "compareFilters": [ { "compareType": "EQUAL", "fieldName": " settlementDate", "fieldValue": "2018-09-14 00:00:00" } ] } ' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST https://api.finra.org/data/group/otcMarket/name/EquityShortInterest
```

if you use `curl`, it is recommended that you handle the start time and end time manually.

Comment: Thanks. could you show me how I can manually handle start time and end time in curl tho? I know only python and have been doing some researches on curl online but still no improved for my codes for this case yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the body correctly, data has to be a dictionary. This should work:

```
import requests
import json

headers = { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
       'Accept': 'application/json', 
       }

data = { "compareFilters": [ { "compareType": "EQUAL", "fieldName": " settlementDate", 
"fieldValue": "2018-09-14 00:00:00" } ] }

response = 
requests.post('https://api.finra.org/data/group/otcMarket/name/EquityShortInterest',
                     headers=headers,
                     data=json.dumps(data))
print(response.content)
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Giovanni, but It will still work only for a particular day. It would be much appreciated if you could guide me how I should do it for dates range (start : 2018-09-14 00:00:00 end: 2019-09-14 00:00:00)?

Comment: According to the [doc](https://developer.finra.org/post-data) you should add a dateRangeFilters to the payload of the message, where you insert your dates and a fieldName (which has to be a date type, you can check it by going to this https://api.finra.org/metadata/group/otcMarket/name/EquityShortInterest (notice metadata instead of data)); you can try with "settlementDate", for example.